# Order of elements of a dihedral group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm not sure how to approach this question, and I have a guess:
What are all the possible orders of elements of dihedral group D17?

Since the order of any element in a finite group must divide the order of the group, and the order of D17 is 34, it follows any element of D17 is of order 1 (the identity), 2, 17, or 34.

Is this correct and how I find the possible orders of elements of any finite group?

Comment: There are too many kinds of finite groups to give a general answer about them all. Anyway, just because the order of an element must be a divisor of the group's size doesn't imply for every possible divisor there is an element with that order. In particular, in the dihedral group of order $34$, there is no element of order $34$ (since then it would be cyclic!). Key is recognizing that every element of the dihedral group is either a reflection or in the rotational subgroup of order $n$, which is cyclic. What are the orders of the elements of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$? (Okay, *then* it's all divisors.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea! For sure, we know that if $g \in G$ for some group $G$, that the order of $g$ (denoted $|g|$) divides the order of $G$ (denoted $|G|$). So what you've written is that $1,2,17,34$ are all $\underline{\text{possible}}$ orders of elements of $G$.

However, this does not mean that all divisors of $G$ will have an element of that order; as [anon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11763/anon) pointed out, we know that $34$ is a divisor of the order of $D_{17}$, but that as $D_{17}$ is not cyclic there can't be an element of order 34.

To sum up:

$\left(g \in G\right)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\left(|g| \text{ divides } |G|\right)$

$\left(n \text{ divides } |G|\right)$ $\not\Rightarrow$ $\left( \text{There is some } g \in G \text{ with } |g| = n \right)$